# AzureServiceBus - Publish messages in a guaranteed order

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

When publishing messages to a service bus topic, if I loop over 3 messages:

{ A, B, C }

And **await** the SendAsync() each time, I'd expect them to be published to the topic in the order:

{ A, B, C }

```
public async Task PublishMessage(string topic, string json, string sessionId)
{
       var topicClient = new TopicClient(_connectionString, topic);
       var busMessage = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
       busMessage.SessionId = sessionId;
       await topicClient.SendAsync(busMessage);
}
```

A number of employees have suggested this isn't guaranteed to be the case, and that in certain scenarios (i.e large messages), this publishing order isn't guaranteed. I've never encountered a scenario of this myself, does ASB not guarantee publish ordering even when the sending of messages is awaited like the above?

This article https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/ordering-messages-in-azure-service-bus/ uses this quote:

*"While Azure Service Bus allows for a FIFO approach (First-In-First-Out), we cannot guarantee that messages are entered in the order we want them to be processed"*

This all seems quite baffling to me, as I'd have assumed SendAsync() would only return a successful result once the message has been added into the topic. Do we really need to write layers of complexity around this to manage it?

Please note this only relates to the **publishing** of messages, we use SessionIds to handle consumption.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you wait for one message to be sent and then only send the next one, the FIFO is not guaranteed. This is due to too many probable causes. In order to ensure you get guaranteed ordering, you need to use `session` enabled queues or subscriptions.

Comment: Just to be clear I'm only talking about guaranteed order for publishing here (not consumption) - we already have SessionIds in place for that. Or is there something in session needed to guarantee publishing order?

In simpler words, does SendAsync() return complete only once the message is on the topic?

Comment: In your snippet , you don't set the `session id` property for the published message. AFAIK there is no 'publish' only FIFO, guaranteed order only makes sense end to end, not just for publishing. Internally there is a `sequence number` for each message, see if that is what you need.

Comment: Ah yes sorry I originally removed this to reduce confusion, but I've re-added it so it's clearer. The reason we're only focused on 'sending' here is that the consumption is all fine. But if awaiting SendAsync() does not actually wait for the message to be added to the topic (as some people in my department are theorising), then we have a problem. This is because our code is defining the order of messages (by looping over them), so we need 'await' to not proceed to the next message until service bus has it added into the topic.

Comment: If you needed to send all 3 or nothing, then you can do so in [transaction scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-transactions#transactions-in-service-bus). Since already you have sessions enabled consumption, which will give you FIFO ,  order of 'publishing' is not a concern, nor it is in client's hands, it will be handled by ASB using internal sequence number.

Comment: That is how I understand it also. What's confusing then is the purpose of 'Message Deferral' (see article in question). They use this approach to define an order to the messages. Why do they need to do this when our own code can define such an order in the first place? (by awaiting each SendAsync before proceeding to the next message) My only guess is that this is required for cases when a Task.WhenAll() is performed to publish a large batch of messages, which would of course not provide any procedural order.